# Invoking bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Having a simple script:

```
echo "file: $0"
```

when invoked like so:

> bash myscript.sh

or

> ./myscript.sh

gives file name of the script (`file: myscript.sh`) as expected
but when invoked:

> source myscript.sh

or

> . ./myscript.sh

gives the shell name (`bash`) instead of script file name.

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 2):

The first call will start a new instance of bash to interpret the script, meaning bash will set `$0` to its path.

The second call will treat the file as executable and run it, so `$0` will point to it.

The latter two calls will load the file into the current instance of bash, so `$0` will point there.

NB: #2 needs the file to be executable, #1, #3 and #4 not.

Comment: #1 doesn't need the file to be executable, only #2 does

Comment: Reading more carefully would have helped - thanks for the catch!